# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error while saving Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, file

I am saving data on button's click event and below is code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;

object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
String st = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\A.xlsx";

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(st, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

int i = 6;
for (i = 6; i < 10; i++)
{
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(st, XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("L" + @i, "L" + @i).Value2.ToString());
}

xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

When I am saving it, it gives me error:

> HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error while saving Excel file

Comment: Are you trying to save the same workbook 4 times without a file name change?

Comment: but i am getting error in first time only

Comment: You need to be a little more specific. Do all MessageBoxes pop up? Are you sure the saving process is complete?

Comment: I want to use (xlWorkSheet.get_Range("L" + @i, "L" + @i).Value2.ToString() value..so just now i am showing it in messagebox

Comment: So why do you save your workbook at all? You can get the value without saving it.

Comment: That's Excel error 1004, the same error as [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684).  The workaround they propose is, well, ironic.

Answer (score 3):

check for cell indices for sheet , starts from [1,1] 
sheet.cells[0,0] will throw com error.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand at [Saving an Excel File Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3ecbc477-a5d9-4033-887b-3e7dbaf2b7cb/) Exception raised when arguments of method SaveAs are wrong. Please review your arguments at:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(st1, XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but this may be of help to somebody. I had the same problem, and calling the [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh14x010%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)() function on the workbook fixed it for me:

```
yourWorkBookObject.Activate()
```

Comment: this helped in 2022!!...  if you're using interop and inserting/pasting data from one source to another repeatedly such as from a datagridview to your ws, multiple times etc... re-activating the sheet prior to each paste helped me.  I would get this bug intermittently, sometimes it would work fine, others not.

Answer (score 1):

@Sebastian is correct in that you are calling SaveAs four times, saving to the same location without closing. This isn't going to work, you need to first of all move this out of the loop. But looking at your code more closely, you aren't changing anything in the workbook, so there is no need to save, and if you did change something, you would be better calling **Save** instead of SaveAs. As well as this, you are specifying **ReadOnly** as true when you are opening the workbook, so attempting to call save in any capacity isn't going to work.

Finally, if you are using >= C# 4, you can use optional parameters, so all of those **misValue**'s are unnecessary. I tidied up your code below:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

var st = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\A.xlsx";

var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(st);
var xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item[1];

for (var i = 6; i < 10; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.Range["L" + @i, "L" + @i].Value2.ToString());
}

//make some changes here

xlWorkBook.Save();
xlWorkBook.Close();
xlApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while saving the Excel file line.

```cs
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(st);
```

I found out the folder name has been changed by someone cause an issue for me to save the file to the given file location at "st". I hope this helps someone to check first.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else makes the same mistake  as me, in my case it was due to the filename used to save the excel file. It had an illegal character in the name "/" which was causing this 0x800A03EC Error with no details at all.
So before dealing with permissions make sure that the path exists AND that the filename is legal.