# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, vb.net, windows-task-scheduler

I built a .net application that saves data to excel. When I run the application manually the program saves stuff from the data table into excel. The problem is that when I schedule a task to run on my Windows 10 PC I get the below error.

> :System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.SaveAs(Object Filename, Object FileFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended, Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, Object AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)

```
 Public Shared Function CreateExcel() As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    For retry As Integer = 1 To 5
        Try
            clsScrape.SendMail(" Return New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass")
            Return New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass

            Exit For
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.HResult <> &H80080005 Then Throw ex
        End Try
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Shared Sub ExportExceltest(ByVal excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass)

    Try

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("ID")
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")


        Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        R("Name") = "MY Name"
        dt.Rows.Add(R)

        Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\CodeMonger\Documents\Development\Test" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss") & ".xlsx"
        '  Dim excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
        Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        wBook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
        wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next

        For Each dr In dt.Rows

            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
            Next




        Next

        clsScrape.SendMail("The datatable was built and this is Right before save")

        wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        wBook.SaveAs(strFile)
        wBook.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        clsScrape.SendMail("Here is the Issue     :" & ex.ToString)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the construction code of your Excel object to a factory subroutine that will perform a retry when the exception is caught, like this

```
Function CreateExcel() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    For retry As Integer = 1 To 5
        Try
            Return New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
            Exit For
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.HResult <> &H80080005 Then Throw ex
        End Try
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

This [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/06/24/when-cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-co_e_server_exec_failure/) details the problems which will a CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE:

> This problem can arise for an out of process COM server when
>
> 1. The machine has a high CPU load and the process takes a long time
>      to start and execute the CoRegisterClassObjects() in less than 120
>      seconds.
> 2. The COM server doesn’t register for the right class IDs.
> 3. The COM server is currently stopping and there is a race
>      condition between CoCreateInstance and the COM server stopping part.
> 4. There is a security problem in the way the COM server is started
>      (this page seems to suggest misspelled passwords or lacking the
>      “Login as Batch Job” privilege for “Run As..” COM servers, but
>      anyway I would suggest re-verifying this information for your
>      specific configuration)

Comment: Okay So I tried your suggestion and that did appear to correct the issue

Comment: I changed the code above to incorporate your answer on how I am using the constructor and building the excel.

Comment: @CodeMonger moving forward consider accepting the answer and asking a new one, as the original question/answer may have helped someone in the future.

Your new problem may be a duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597490/exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec-error-while-saving-excel-file).  Double check your file path, check that your program can read/write to the path, etc.